# Is it possible to change the width of edges in edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view, theme

I'm a math teacher.  I like to use Blender to demonstrate some ideas when we talk about geometry in 3 dimensions, so I display it on our projector and the class will work together to edit some basic shapes.  I've changed the size of vertices so they are bigger and easier to see, but I haven't found a way to increase the size of edges.  Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Has far as I know this isn't currently configurable. maybe in the upcoming viewport refactor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. You can edit vertex and face dot size but not edge thickness.

[image]

I defer to the other answer for the (easy?) workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand your question.

Don't use wireframe mode. Instead, use solid mode and use the wireframe modifier. Here is a quick recording using the mathematical object hexagonalmonkeyprismoidalsphere:[image]

Comment: The wireframe modifier is a nice idea, but I want to still be able to see the solid geometry.  I was really just hoping to be able to change how edges appear so they're easier to see on a projected screen.

Comment: @Jason You can uncheck the "Replace Original" button, and then you can change the material index of the wireframe

Comment: Only one downside I see here is that it will only work with objects which have faces.... I use wireframe meshes also for similar things and often I need to have edges only...

Answer (score 3):

You can change the width of the lines in the interface tab of the Blender preferences.
This will also increase the thickness of the lines in the interface, but perhaps this will suit your needs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although if in edit mode and your creating a whatever.... Yes the vertices can be made to thick.  but, the edges cannot.  There is a way to help though.  Go to user preferences and increase the scale of the display.  look under interface, then display.  Increasing the scale, or zoom make it appear that the edges are thicker.  in reality its the same size but, when its scaled to sale 105 or more the edges are a lot thicker looking. and easier to see and it really doesn't effect the work area field of view.