# Changing the edge width in edit mode

Tags: edges

I've been watching BlenderGuru's tutorials, and his lines in edit mode are much thicker than mine.

https://youtu.be/9ViVKUiG8ks?t=3m51s

You can see, his lines are solid 2-3 pixel wide, mine are only 1. They also seem to disappear when I zoom in really close. Any fixes?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. Was looking for the same solution as you want some time ago. Related answer BTW: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67519/is-it-possible-to-change-the-width-of-edges-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in the current version. It may happen when 2.8 gets released but in the Blender Guru tutorial, he just zoomed the whole view. I suspect since his mouse cursor is still small that he's using the [**magnifier**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier) in Windows. Every operating system ([Mac](http://www.wikihow.com/Zoom-in-on-a-Mac), [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609398/is-there-a-magnifier-app-for-ubuntu-i-want-to-use-a-bounding-box-with-the-mouse)) has this functionality.