# How to make the outline of the cut clearer with Knife Project?

Tags: knife-tool

This is my result of knife project

[image]

and this one is when I saw some tutorial,

[image]

is it just about the setting of the view, or maybe there's a way to make the mesh clearer?

Comment: Please don't use all caps. [Why typing in all-caps looks like you’re yelling](https://www.cnn.com/2018/07/23/us/all-caps-typography-history-tweets-trnd/index.html)

Comment: @susu thank susu

Comment: according to this answer you can set the vertex size but not the edge thickness: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67519/is-it-possible-to-change-the-width-of-edges-in-edit-mode